# T-Sql Modify Insert SProc To Update If Exists

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

#### Scenario

I have a stored procedure written in T-Sql that I use to insert data into a table as XML.
Since the data gets updated regularly, I want the rows to be updated if they already exist (Aside from when the application is first run, they will always exist).

#### Question

Below is the code of my Insert Sproc, however I cannot seem to workout the Update side of the stored procedure & would appreciate some help.

#### CODE

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INS_Curve] 
(
 @Curve varchar(MAX)
)
AS
DECLARE @handle int
 exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @Curve

 INSERT INTO CurveDB..tblCurve(LoadID,BusinessDate, Factor)
  SELECT LoadID,BusinessDate, Factor
  FROM OPENXML(@handle, 'NewDataSet/Table1',2)
  WITH(
  LoadID int,
  BusinessDate DateTime,
  Factor float
  ) 

   exec sp_xml_removedocument @handle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than inserting directly into the target table, put the data in the XML Document into a temporary table and then INSERT/UPDATE the target from there...

```
DECLARE @tabTemporary TABLE
(
  LoadID INT,
  BusinessDate DATETIME,
  Factor FLOAT
)

exec sp_xml_preparedocument @handle OUTPUT, @Curve

 INSERT INTO @tabTemporary (LoadID,BusinessDate, Factor)
  SELECT LoadID,BusinessDate, Factor
  FROM OPENXML(@handle, 'NewDataSet/Table1',2)
  WITH(
  LoadID int,
  BusinessDate DateTime,
  Factor float
  )

exec sp_xml_removedocument @handle

 INSERT INTO CurveDB..tblCurve
 ( LoadID, BusinessDate, Factor )
 SELECT LoadID, BusinessDate, Factor
 FROM @tabTemporary T1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
 SELECT 1 FROM CurveDB..tblCurve T2 WHERE T1.LoadID = T2.LoadID
 )

 UPDATE T1
 SET T1.BusinessDate = T2.BusinessDate, T1.Factor = T2.Factor
 FROM CurveDB..tblCurve T1
 INNER
 JOIN @tabTemporary T2
 ON T1.LoadID = T2.LoadID
```

Note: I've assumed that "LoadID" is a unique/primary key

**UPDATE**

There's also the ["UPSERT" functionality](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) introduced in Sql Server 2008 that may be of interest.